# Split Records in Table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse

I have an table with the below records

| PREFIX | BEGIN | END | DIV | INDUSTRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1AB | 00001 | 99999 | LPSD | RI |
| 1AB | 00527 | 00528 | MHUG | RI |

I want to split it as below

| PREFIX | BEGIN | END | DIV | INDUSTRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1AB | 00001 | 99999 | LPSD | RI |
| 1AB | 00527 | 00528 | MHUG | RI |
| 1AB | 00529 | 99999 | LPSD | RI |

If you see as because we have a record with the same prefix but begin and end are different, i want to split the first record into 2 records, one from 00001 to 00526 and 00529 to 99999.

Is it possible to perform the same using the SQL query

Comment: Can there be three records with the same prefix?  what are the data types?

Comment: Yes.. For now all attributes are of string data type. the three records can be as below  1AB  00001   04000 LPSD and 1AB 04001 99999 DABP and 1AB 02112 02115 MHUG in this case the output would be 4 records as 1AB  00001   02111 LPSD and 1AB 02115 04000 LPSD and 1AB 02112 02115 MHUG and 1AB 04001 99999 DABP

Comment: This looks difficult. You must generate rows. The SQL way to do this is to write a recursive query that loops through your data. The other option is a pipelined PL/SQL function. There might be other options. Some kind of cross joins maybe based on starts and ends or Oracle's model clause. I don't know. Think of how you would solve this in a programming language and then either use one (PL/SQL) or convert the loop into a recursive query. I am sorry this is all the advice I can give you, as my time is too limited to work on this.

Comment: I suppose the 00528 should be a 00529 in the third line in your scrrenshot?

Comment: yes sorry its a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works (but it would need a bigger data set to test it properly):

```sql
SELECT prefix,
       "BEGIN",
       "END",
       CASE type
       WHEN 1
       THEN div
       ELSE LAG(CASE type WHEN 1 THEN div END) IGNORE NULLS
              OVER (PARTITION BY prefix, industry, grp ORDER BY "BEGIN")
       END AS div,
       industry
FROM   (
  SELECT prefix,
         div,
         industry,
         value AS "BEGIN",
         type,
         SUM(type) OVER (PARTITION BY prefix, industry ORDER BY value) AS grp,
         LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY prefix, industry ORDER BY value) AS "END"
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT (value FOR type IN ("BEGIN" AS 1, "END" AS -1))
)
WHERE  grp > 0
ORDER BY prefix, industry, "BEGIN";
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (prefix, "BEGIN", "END", div, industry) AS
SELECT '1AB', '00001', '99999', 'LPSD', 'RI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1AB', '00527', '00528', 'MHUG', 'RI' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PREFIX | BEGIN | END | DIV | INDUSTRY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1AB | 00001 | 00527 | LPSD | RI |
> | 1AB | 00527 | 00528 | MHUG | RI |
> | 1AB | 00528 | 99999 | LPSD | RI |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=19ccaeec0067fe099a3f630e04d8dbbb)*

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not a good practice to name columns after reserved words (like Begin, End ...). This could be solved using MODEL clause like this...

```
    WITH
        tbl AS
            (   Select '1AB' "PRFX", '00001' "BGN", '99999' "ND", 'LPSD' "DV", 'RI' "IND" From Dual UNION ALL
                Select '1AB' "PRFX", '00527' "BGN", '00528' "ND", 'MHUG' "DV", 'RI' "IND" From Dual
            ) 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        m.*,
        t.DV "DV",
        t.IND "IND"
    FROM
        (
    SELECT
        INDX,
        PRFX, BGN, ND
    FROM
        (   SELECT
                PRFX "PRFX",
                LISTAGG(BGN, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRFX, BGN) "BGN",
                LISTAGG(ND, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRFX, ND) "ND"
            FROM
                tbl 
            GROUP BY
                PRFX
        )
    MODEL
        DIMENSION BY(0 as INDX)
        MEASURES (PRFX, BGN, ND)
            RULES ITERATE(3) 
                (   PRFX[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = PRFX[0],
                    BGN[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = Nvl(SubStr(REPLACE(BGN[0], ',', ''), (ITERATION_NUMBER*5) + 1, 5), LPAD(To_Number(SubStr(REPLACE(ND[0], ',', ''), ((ITERATION_NUMBER-2)*5) + 1, 5)) + 1, 5, '0')),
                    ND[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = CASE 
                                                WHEN SubStr(REPLACE(BGN[0], ',', ''), ((ITERATION_NUMBER+1)*5) + 1, 5) < SubStr(REPLACE(ND[0], ',', ''), (ITERATION_NUMBER*5) + 1, 5) THEN
                                                    LPAD(To_Number(SubStr(REPLACE(BGN[0], ',', ''), ((ITERATION_NUMBER+1)*5) + 1, 5)) - 1, 5, '0')
                                              ELSE 
                                                  SubStr(REPLACE(ND[0], ',', ''), ((ITERATION_NUMBER-1)*5) + 1, 5) 
                                              END
                )
        ) m
    LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT 
                PRFX, DV, 
                IND, 
                Max(ND) OVER(PARTITION BY PRFX, DV ORDER BY PRFX, DV) "MAX_ND",
                Min(BGN) OVER(PARTITION BY PRFX, DV ORDER BY PRFX, DV) "MIN_BGN"
            FROM 
                tbl
        )  t ON (t.PRFX = m.PRFX And (t.MAX_ND = m.ND OR t.MIN_BGN = m.BGN)) 
WHERE
    m.INDX > 0 And ND Is Not Null
ORDER BY 
    m.INDX
    --
    -- Result
    -- INDX PRFX BGN    ND      DV      IND
    -- 1    1AB  00001  00526   LPSD    RI
    -- 2    1AB  00527  00528   MHUG    RI
    -- 3    1AB  00529  99999   LPSD    RI
```

Hopefully it will help. Regards...